# How to render UIView into a CGContext

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, uiview, cgcontext

I Wanted to render a UIView into a CGContextRef

```
-(void)methodName:(CGContextRef)ctx {
    UIView *someView = [[UIView alloc] init];

    MagicalFunction(ctx, someView);
}
```

So, the MagicalFunction here is supposed to render the UIView(may be its layer) into current context.

How do I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about the renderInContext method of [CALayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)?

```
-(void)methodName:(CGContextRef)ctx {
    UIView *someView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [someView.layer renderInContext:ctx];
}
```

**EDIT:** As noted in the comment, due to a difference in origins in the two coordinate systems involved in the process, the layer will be rendered upside-down. To compensate, you just need to flip the context vertically. This is technically done with a scale and translation transformation, which can be combined in a single matrix transformation:

```
-(void)methodName:(CGContextRef)ctx {
    UIView *someView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    CGAffineTransform verticalFlip = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, someView.frame.size.height);
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, verticalFlip);
    [someView.layer renderInContext:ctx];
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! But the views are rendered upside down! Any suggestions?

Comment: do you know how to move the someView.layer before it gets rendered?  For example I have a long view I need toi plit up over several pages so I will need to adjust my view before rendering it to the second page.

Comment: @PsychoDad, this method is independent of `drawRect`. If you have overridden `drawRect` to do some custom drawing in a view, it will be rendered into the context as-is.