# Erica Saduns iPhone Developers Cookbook (3.0) Chap 08, Exercise 14 — Resize and Rotate

Tags: ios, uiimageview, gestures

Regarding Erica Sadun's iPhone Developer Cookbook, in [Chapter 8, Exercise 14 Resize and Rotate](https://github.com/erica/iphone-3.0-cookbook-/tree/master/C08-Gestures/14-Resize%20And%20Rotate): the example works just fine, I am able to rotate, resize and whatever. The issue is, how do you reference the altered image after it has been scaled, rotate? When attempting to save the photo, it is saved as the original photo and not the edited one.

Comment: A code sample may prove useful.

Comment: Exactly, thats why I referenced the source code in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are resizing and rotating a `UIImageView` that is visible on the device's screen.  If this is the case, then your manipulations are being applied as matrix transformations on the `UIView` when it renders, and are not actually modifying the backing image at all.  So if you want to save a snapshot of the image's current state, then you need to draw your view into an appropriately-sized `CGContext`, and then create a new image from that context.

You may find these resources helpful:

[How to render UIView into a CGContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041403/how-ro-render-uiview-into-a-cgcontext)

http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

Comment: Okay, so I have used layers to save the view; it works to an extent. My saved image needs to be **640x960**, where as the main layer is half that, so the image is saved half the original size. any ideas? I have updated my question.